# Unresolved symbols for androidTest dependencies in case of non-standard build types

Tags: android, android-studio, testing, android-instrumentation

When I've decided to add instrumentation tests, I found that `androidTestImplementation` dependencies are not recognized. In my test file related classes like `RunWith` were displayed as `Unresolved symbols`.
When I've tried to run the test anyway, in run configuration there was a message: `Error: Instrumentation runner class not specified.`". I've checked, instrumentation runner class was explicitly specified in build.gradle.

I use custom build types like debugDev, debugProd.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that if non-standard build types are used, it's needed to select a build config for running instrumented tests. It can be done by using `testBuildType "nameOfBuildType"` in `android {...}` in a module's build.gradle.